# Nice way to test if an object chain in JavaScript is valid

Tags: javascript

Considering this example:

```
    if(this.plantService.plants[id])
    {
        if(this.plantService.plants[id].Name)
        {
            if(this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0])
                return this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0].value;
            else
                return '';
        }
        else
            return '';        
    }    
    return '';
```

I am wondering if it is possible to simplify what I am doing here.

My goal is to test the object-chain `this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0]` for validity.

However, if I just test `if(this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0]) {...}` exceptions are thrown.

Any proposals? :)

Comment: you could use the `&&` operator in your if like this: `if(this.plantService.plants[id] && this.plantService.plants[id].Name && this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0]){return this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0].value} else {return ''}`

Comment: Please show us the exception thrown. you only say there is, but what is that?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy It would be a `TypeError`, as you'd be attempting to access a property on `undefined`.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy accessing variable of `undefined`

Comment: You could [catch the exception](http://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_errors.asp).

Comment: Which bit exactly are you trying to test? The entire chain? So any of those objects could be `undefined`?

Comment: I was just going to say, you could do a try/catch, it'll either be undefined or the value so just have an exception when undefined is returned and instead return your empty character. I'd write it out but don't have the time at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the array with the object, after checking value and type.

```js
function getIn(object, keys, def)  {
    return keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o && typeof o === 'object' && k in o ? o[k] : def;
    }, object);
}

var object = { plantService: { plants: [{ Name: [{ value: 42 }] }] } };

console.log(getIn(object, ['plantService', 'plants', 0, 'Name', 0, 'value'], 'default value'));
console.log(getIn(object, ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'default value'));
```

Comment: Probably the nicest way for me... nevertheless I hoped there was something nicer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple function on your own like,

```
function getVal(obj, propQueue, defaultValue) {
  for (var prop of propQueue) {
    if ((obj = obj[prop]) === undefined) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return obj || defaultValue;
}
```

Now you can call it like,

```
var value = getVal(this, ["plantService", "plants", id, "name" 0], "");
console.log(value); //either "" or the real value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(this.plantService.plants[id] && this.plantService.plants[id].Name && this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0]){
        return this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0].value;

        }else{

    return '';
}
```

Or maybe your problem is that your model is not complete and you need to be sure of that in order to prevent these validations and replace with this:

```
return this.plantService.plants[id].Name[0].value;
```